# Rearranging order of each element in array

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, geojson

My application reads every linestring in a GeoJSON file with JQuery :

```
$.getJSON("testROUTES.geojson", function (dat) {

    $.each(dat.features, function (key, val) {

      var line = val.geometry.coordinates
      console.log(line)
      console.log(line[0])

    });
});
```

However the order of the lat/lon coordinates needs to be switched.  For example, the above code returns:
[image]

How would one rearrange the coordinates in `var line` so that the coordinates would read `[45,-122]` instead of `[-122,45]` with Jquery?

Comment: line.push(line.shift())

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `map`

```
val.geometry.coordinates = val.geometry.coordinates.map((coords) => {
    return [coords[1], coords[0]]
});
```

Answer (score 4):

You can try just using JavaScript's [Array.prototype.reverse](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reverse) method.

```
var line = val.geometry.coordinates.reverse()
```

Comment: thanks, but when I try this the lat/lon values are returned in the same order, maybe because they are arrays within an array

Comment: That's odd, I just ran the same script on a geojson file and it worked. Anyhow, the map function should work for you if reverse does not.

Answer (score 0):

An interesting ES6 way of doing this would be,

```
[line[0], line[1]] = [line[1], line[0]]
```